# Angular click event of p-listbox of primeNg does not work

Tags: angular, primeng

I have this listbox de primeNg in Angular, where I have a list of item, each elemet have a click event where execute the funcion searchQuery(recentSearch), in turn, also each item have a button where eliminates the item selected calling the funtion elimnateItem(). My problem is when I click over the item the click event does not work. Any idea how to resolve this? I am using angular 14: this is my html code

```
<div class="row m-0 p-0 category-card-size">
    <p-listbox [options]="recentSearches" [(ngModel)]="selectedSearch"  class="custom-listbox">
        <ng-template let-recentSearch pTemplate="item">
            <div class="search-item" >
                <div class="search-content">
                    <i class="material-symbols-outlined icon-fs-20px ms-2">manage_search</i>
                    
                    <a (click)="searchQuery(recentSearch)"><span>{{ recentSearch.title.join(' ') }}</span> </a>
                </div>
                <div class="ms-auto">
                    <div class="button-container">
                        <button pButton type="button"                                                      
                            icon="pi pi-times" 
                            class="p-button-text p-button-secondary"                                
                            (click)="elimnateItem(recentSearch)">
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ng-template>
    </p-listbox>
</div>
```

Comment: The event click  when I try to call the funtion elimnateItem() or searchQuery()

Comment: The click event is already matched by p-listbox probably. Any chance to make a stackblitz?

Comment: I want to see if it is possible for both of them to be independent

Comment: check this one out : [click event not working in primeng list box inside template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65705786/click-event-not-working-in-primeng-list-box-inside-template)